# How to speed up Query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using PHP-Mysql for my project, and i have a table with more 30000 rows.

When my code access to that table, request time too long.

How i can get more speed? or some way to do that?

I'm using Laravel 5.1. My code like this (don't worry about correct or not):

```
Games::join('categories', 'categories.id_game', '=', 'games.id')->where('games.id', $id)
->select('games.*', 'categories.name')->get()->toArray();
```

Table `Games` has more 30000 rows and i used `index`(id) for table `Games`.

**Updated**: I just need 1~300 records at once. But query request is too long time. I think problem from table `games` have so much rows. I'm finding solution for this. I tried some way: set `index` for table `games`, just select field(games name, categories name) what i need.

**Sorry about my English!**

Comment: Why do you need to use ->select() if you can do Games::where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();

Comment: @JohnRoca I'm sorry, i often don't use ->select(). I just select() when i want select some field in table. Question updated

Comment: Why are you returning 30000 rows it the real question?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Table `Games` is large size, some code request too long time when access to table `Games`. Before, table `Games` is small size, query so fast, but now is very lowly. Do you have solution for this?

Comment: Try the same with `DB::table('games')->join('categories', 'categories.id_game')...`; Try to run it again and compare both times. Also I think you should (or not) reorganise your database so that `games` will have `category_id` rather than `categories` having `id_game` as a foreign key

Comment: Can you show us your tables?

Comment: You can get more speed by returning less records.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do you really need 3000 records at once? Think about pagination / split into parts.
2. In Laravel Models are **$visible** and **$hidden** attribute that determine columns to serialize.

```
protected $visible = ['id', 'name', 'age'];
```

If you serialize model by **toArray()** or **toJson()** method, you can get only the information you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I just need 1~300 records at once. But query request is too long time. I think problem from table `games` have so much rows.

Comment: Try to use **skip** and **take** method as limit your query:  
    `$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use pagination as suggested by @miikes above.
2. id_game in categories table is indexed too? if not index that too.
3. if using Mysql Workbench try to review the execution plan and tweak accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm trying every way from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said - the most likely two explanations are:

1. It takes a long time for 30,000 records to be read, transferred, processed and put into an array.  (You'll probably also see quite a large amount of memory being chewed by PHP...)
2. There's a lack of indexes somewhere.

A lack of indexes can be identified by using `EXPLAIN`.  I won't go into the details here, you can [Google it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=using%20explain%20to%20optimise%20mysql%20queries).  I'd firstly double check there are appropriate indexes on the `JOIN`.

But your query is actually a very simple one.  So vastly more likely is the "perceived" query duration.  It takes a relatively long time for MySQL to read all those records, put them in memory, format them, deliver them over the TCP/IP stack, for PHP to receive them, to process them into an array, etc.

Consider (as others have already said) using a `LIMIT` clause to reduce the number of records returned.  (An primary-key indexed `ORDER BY` will ensure you always get the same results for a given `LIMIT` statement.)

Finally (but I suspect this is lowest-likelihood): we can't see the table structures.  Are they very wide?  Perhaps `BLOB` or `TEXT` fields inside?  If we assume an average record is large (say 2KB), then 30,000 records will be 58MB of data.  It might be appropriate to cache some larger lookup-data in PHP first.

---

It also occurs to me that you might be stuck in the common rut of solving a problem that doesn't exist.

You're returning *everything*, but are you actually *using* everything in the code that follows?  (You've already said you only need ~300 rows at a time.)

I've worked on some seriously large databases (as I'm certain others people answering have too) - sometimes it's the problem that needs to change, not the solution.

Normalisation in databases is academically good, but can in reality be really bad.  Don't fear duplicating data for the purpose of an efficient, summarised cache.  Consider changing the *problem* such that less data has to be dealt with.  Forcing updates and deletes through transactionally safe stored procedures can let you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: May be you right, my table have a `TEXT` field with more 80~5000 words. And my Query join 3~4 table, I was limited records is 200. And my Database about 90MB.